# Merge tags [linkedin] and [linkedin-api]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

I propose merging the tags [linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin) and [linkedin-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin-api). Both are used for LinkedIn API questions.

[linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin) (3,314 questions)

> A tool used for finding business/networking connections, such as for suggesting job candidates. **Used for questions regarding LinkedIn's APIs.** Do not ask questions about LinkedIn's terms of service, problems with registering for a service with them, or what APIs they will be offering in the future. They are not appropriate for asking on StackOverflow, *even if* LinkedIn appeared to direct you here.

[linkedin-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin-api) (652 questions)

> Open web-services and APIs provided by LinkedIn

Comment: Sounds good. I think `linkedin-api` should remain, as tags for company names have a storied history here...

Comment: I prefer the discussion that was more active to be the target.