# These two tags are [LinkedIn]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

The tag-excerpt of [linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin) says:

> A tool used for finding business/networking connections, such as for suggesting job candidates. **Used for questions regarding LinkedIn's APIs**. Do not ask questions about LinkedIn's terms of service, problems with registering for a service with them, or what APIs they will be offering in the future. They are not appropriate for asking on Stack Overflow, *even if* LinkedIn appeared to direct you here.

bold emphasis mine. Looking a bit further, I found [linkedin-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin-api) with the very short excerpt:

> Open web-services and APIs provided by LinkedIn

It looks like [linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin) can only be used by questions having to do with its APIs, thus should we merge the two tags? And if so, which one should be kept?

Apparently LinkedIn is an OAuth provider as well, so besides the merge-question: should we create [linkedin-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin-oauth)?

At the very least I'd say the tag wikis need to be rewritten; the excerpt of [linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin) needs a mention of OAuth and the [linkedin-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin-api) needs better user guidance.

---

At the time of this question:

- [linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin): 3,487 questions Updated (Open): 3,561
- [linkedin-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin-api): 828 questions Updated (Open):  951
- [572 questions with both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin+linkedin-api) Updated (Open): 664

Related: [Merge tags [linkedin] and [linkedin-api]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363485/merge-tags-linkedin-and-linkedin-api)

Comment: >It looks like linkedin can only be used by questions having to do with its APIs. I would say linkedin-api bc of what you said?

Comment: LinkedIn also is an OAuth provider, and there are many questions about that. I think those are appropriate for SO, but probably shouldn't get tagged linkedin-api, since it's not a LinkedIn-specific API.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth so you are suggesting the tag excerpt of [linkedin]  should be rewritten, or do we need [linkedin-oauth]? (And probably that of [linkedin-api] extended)

Comment: Creating a [foo-api] tag is a pretty standard desperation move when the [foo] tag gets too many offtopic end-user questions.  It did not work, both tags are moribund with only ~20% of the questions getting an answer.  [linkedin-api] actually shows worse with only 1 in 3 questions getting an answer over the lifetime of the tag, [linkedin] got 1 in 2.  Probably looks better due to SO only being known to programmers in the early days.  Although it doesn't really matter anymore, trying to undo that desperation move is unlikely to be appreciated.

Comment: @Adriaan Mostly just an observation that makes merging them problematic. We could leave it as-is, perhaps edit the LinkedIn excerpt to specify that questions about OAuth are also on-topic

Comment: Note that Hans comment is conflating two issue: topicness of the questions regularly asked and whenever questions are answered timely. Changing to the -api variant was only meant to solve the first issue. The later, isn't a problem that the tag name can effect, but lack of experts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some searching didn't yield any real differences between the two tags. The lion's share of the [linkedin] tag appeared to be API questions.

I have merged the tags as a result. It's not useful to users asking these questions to have two tags, and we prefer to not have [company] tags.

Answer (score 10):

[linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin) is a company, and as such having its own tag does not provide much value, therefore I propose to burninate it, following the precedent of tags like [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft), [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple), [htc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htc) etc.

Questions about LinkedIn's API should be retagged [linkedin-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin-api), questions about LinkedIn's OAuth should be retagged with a to be created [linkedin-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin-oauth). In case different valid uses of LinkedIn related questions come up, tags can be created as necessary.

The tag wiki and excerpt of [linkedin-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin-api) need to be updated to properly describe its contents and usage guidance.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, LinkedIn is a business and a service, so it's not directly comparable with [tag:Microsoft], etc